# Trying to run php script that checks for a deadline in mysql db and sends an email to user in same db

Tags: php

I have been searching stackoverflow all over but just cannot find a solution to my problem. I am trying to set up a php script (for a cron job) that detects in my db if a current date has been met and sends an email to that user. I cant get it to run for whatever reason. Maybe you guys see it on the spot?

The table has the following entries:

date = the date that is being checked
email = the email address the reminder should be send to

Here is the code of the php script:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/plain");

// OPEN DATA BASE
    define("HOSTNAME");
    define("USERNAME");
    define("PASSWORD");
    define("DATABASE");

    mysql_connect(hostname, username, password) or die("Connection to database failed!");
    mysql_select_db(database); 

    taskdeadline();


// MAIN FUNCTION
function taskdeadline() {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE date = NOW()");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 $task = row['task'];
 $mail_to = $row['email'];

   if (!empty($mail_to)){

sendEmail($mail_to);

echo "E-Mail send to $mail_to. \n";
   }
}
}


// SEND EMAIL FUNCTION
function sendEmail($mail_to, $task) {
$from    = "my@emailaddress.com";
$message = "Hello! You are the user with the email address $email and the task $task. Your deadline has been reached.";
$headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n" .
'Reply-To:'.$_POST['email']."\r\n" .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n".
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($mail_to, $message, $headers);
}

?>
```

Comment: the table also has the entry task

Comment: I'd rather use a CRON job or something similar for this - your code relies on a person visiting a specific page to run the script. You can set up scheduled tasks to take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$task = row['task'];
```

must be

```
$task = $row['task'];
```

Comment: please elaborate on your answer, explaining what the code does and how it solves the problem - this will help others in the future who see your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of date? If you want to evaluate it then it must be either a timestamp or datetime or date field.

If you are matching a date type field, then use CURDATE() instead of NOW(). I would also check for

```
WHERE date >= CURDATE()
```

so you catch any that have already passed.

Comment: Thx for asking the date type is DATE

Comment: @NuriK - ok, so does this now work if you use CURDATE() instead of NOW() ?

Comment: thx for the suggestion. it didnt work though with CURDATE() instead of NOW()...i will keep looking and post if solved ...